# I am using CloudFront and Cloudflare at the same time. Is that good?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

I'm running my site using two CDNs. I primarily just use Cloudflare for security, and CloudFront for complete CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely get better performance out of using Cloudflare alone for both security and performance.

Cloudflare has the following performance advantages of Cloudfront:

- [CDN WebP support](https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-very-webp-new-year-from-cloudflare/) in Polish
- [Support for HPACK](https://blog.cloudflare.com/hpack-the-silent-killer-feature-of-http-2/) in their HTTP/2 implementation
- Ability to [cache anonymous page views](https://blog.cloudflare.com/caching-anonymous-page-views/) with WordPress
- Railgun

Additionally, Cloudflare has Flat rate pricing so no need to worry about bandwidth fluctuation, unlike with Amazon. In terms of network size, AWS in 16 cities where Cloudflare is in 101.